# How to run command line of pip one by one using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I am trying to make a software using python and I want to install all module in user computer.

```
import os
os.system('cmd /k "color a & pip install instaloader"')
```

I am using this code but it run for a while, means that after second line it do not work, it stops.

```
import os
os.system('cmd /k "color a & pip install instaloader"')
print('done')
```

print('done') is not working....:(

Need some help Fast.... Plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try

```
import os
os.system("color a & pip install instaloader")
print('done')
```

or

```
import os
os.system('cmd /C "color a & pip install instaloader"')
print('done')
```

Comment: Not working print(done), sir anything else...... plz

Comment: that was my mistake.....sorry this is working sir Thankyou